# Using slope and javascript for a responsive web design

Tags: javascript, css, math

Here is what the website looks like:
[image]

The bottom right text 'COMING SOON' should not go in to the white space on the left. At any moment I can adjust the angle of the white divide so that it does not collide with the text.

Here is one example of the viewport being at its limit with the viewport having a height of X and a width of Y:[image]

Here is a second example of the viewport being at its limit with the viewport having a height of X2 and a width of Y2:
[image]

Here is the CSS for the white divide:

```
.white-slanted {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border-top: 100vh solid white;
  border-right: 60vw solid transparent;
}
```

I'm guessing that I can take the two pairs of viewport dimensions, graph it, and one side of the line will be OK and the other side of the line will be broken. I can dynamically change the CSS properties of the white divide with Javascript...I just don't know the math on how to make the next step.

Does anyone have any ideas? :D

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have a specific ratio `r` in mind between 0 and 1 that describes where should your text be positioned vertically - 0 is at the bottom of the slope and 1 is at the top.

If *AB* is the slope you are referring to than `AQ = r * AB`.

Because the triangles *ABE* and *AQC* are similar it is true that: 
`AC = r * AE` and `CQ = r * EB`.

But because we know *EB* (your right border size) and AE (your top border size). we can find the coordinates of the point *Q*. And also if needed the coordinates of the point *D*.

[image]

Now that we can find *Q* and *D* we have everything we need to calculate the values you require.

- *r* - ratio.
- *B<sub>t</sub>* - top border size.
- *B<sub>r</sub>* - right border size.
- *S<sub>w</sub>* - white-slanted width
- *S<sub>h</sub>* - white-slanted height

The coordinates you are looking for are:

- *Q<sub>x</sub>* = *S<sub>w</sub>* + *B<sub>r</sub>* * *r*
- *Q<sub>y</sub>* = *B<sub>t</sub>* * *r*
- *QD* = *B<sub>r</sub>* * *r*

In terms of `CSS` this means for given:

- ratio - *0.5* (lets take the middle for example)
- border top - *100vh*
- border right - *60vw*
- width - *80vw*
- height - *100vh*

your point will be:

```
left: 110vw; /* 80vw + 60vw * 0.5; */
top: 50vh; /*100vh * (1 - 0.5) */
width: 30vh; /* 60vw * (1 - 0.5) */
```

Here is a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/j0cfy440/

You can also use small offset values like add *1 or 2 vw/vh* to `left` and `top` and subtract it form `width` so the text wouldn't be attached right on the slope.